# Вывести последнюю запись wordpress

Tags: wordpress

В админке создаю 2 записи.

Использую ф-ию [wp_get_recent_posts()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_get_recent_posts).

Код стандартный:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'      => 1,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => 0,
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => '',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'draft, publish, future, pending, private',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
); 

$result = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $result as $post ){
    setup_postdata( $post );
    the_title(); // вывод
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

На странице нужно вывести всего одну последнюю запись.

Вывод происходит, но на страниц видна первая запись, а не крайняя. С датой опубликования все в порядке (первая - прошлый месяц, крайняя - сегодня).

**Вопрос:** как вывести всего одну и именно последнюю запись на странице в wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог [WP_Query](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query):

```
<?php 
  $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'      => 1,
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish'
  ); 

  $query = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
      $query->the_post(); ?>
        ...
   <?php } 
   wp_reset_postdata();
  } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
```

Comment: @HamSter Лишние параметры удали из массива

Comment: попробовала, ничего не меняется

Comment: @HamSter Я попробовал у себя - все впорядке. Мой тестовый код: `$data = wp_get_recent_posts([
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
]);
foreach ($data as $post): setup_postdata($post);
var_dump($post);
endforeach;
exit;`